# Nonlinear LS regression of $y(x) = a_1e^{b_1x} + a_2e^{b_2x} + \cdots + a_ne^{b_nx}$ and programming

Tags: calculus, regression

as my first question I am trying to write a program that determines the coefficients $a_i$ in least-squares-sense of

$$
y(x) = a_1e^{b_1x} + a_2e^{b_2x} + \cdots + a_ne^{b_nx},
$$

where $b_n$ are given constants and usually $n\leq 5$.

The problem is that I can't use Matlab or similar tools, so that I have to code the algorithm for the determination of the cofficients by myself. Unfortunately I have only done linear regression by now and don't really know how to start or if there exists a (fast) proper algorithm that could be used.

So,

- How should I start and what could be the best method to solve this problem?
- Is there maybe an open-source implementation of such algorithm that I can use for my problem? (I have to translate it into a very "low-level" scripting-language that only knows for-Loops, conditions and some basic-maths-functions like $\exp(\dots), \ln(\dots),$ etc.

Many thanks in advance and best wishes from Austria,
  JoDoh

Comment: What are the inputs for the program?

Comment: The inputs are the given values $b_n$, a vector containing $x$ and another vector containing the values $Y$ which should then be best-fitted through $y(x)$ with the best choice for $a_n$ (which I am trying to figure out).

Comment: You want to minimize $$ \int_I \left[y(x)-\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k e^{b_k x}\right]^2\,dx $$ over which interval $I$ ?

Comment: Yes (with the "benefit" that $b_k$ are known in advance). The interval defined by the given $x$, lets say from $x_A$ to $x_B$, where $x_A >= 0$ and $x_B>x_A$.

Comment: and $x_A$, $x_B$ are always real numbers, ranging from 0 to 1000. So $I$ can be $1,2,3.5,6,7,8,10.5,20,30,...,100$ or something like that.

Comment: I think that the problem might be solveable in linear least square-sense, because the $e^{b_k\cdot x}$ are constants of the resulting linear system of equations. ... I just wonder how to scale this system because $e^{1000}$ is quite a large number and might not be available in single-precision float 32-bit. Are there some "scaling" techniques? The constants $b_i$ on the other hand vary from $-1/1$ to $-1/1000$ and therefor the system of equations seems to be badly scaled to me.

Comment: As already pointed out this is a linear regression problem. Excel will do linear regression for you (Linest).

Answer (score 0):

$$
y(x_k) = a_1e^{b_1x_k} + a_2e^{b_2x_k} + \cdots + a_ie^{b_ix_k} + \cdots + a_ne^{b_nx_k} \quad\text{for}\quad k=1 \text{ to } N.
$$
$N$ is the number of points : measurements $(x_k,y_k)$ . $n$ is the number of exponential terms.

If the parameters $b_i$ are known, this is a simple problem of linear regression :

First, compute all the $X_{i,k}=e^{b_i x_k}$ for the given values of $x$.
The initial data $(x_1, \cdots , x_k , \cdots , x_N)$ is transformed into $(X_{1,k}, \cdots , X_{i,k} , \cdots , X_{n,k})$ for $k$=$1$ to $N$.
$$
y(X_k) = a_1X_{1,k} + a_2X_{2,k} + \cdots + a_iX_{i,k} + \cdots + a_nX_{n,k},
$$
Second, compute the approximate values of $a_i$ thanks to an usual linear regression.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression

So, the problem is solved (insofar the numerical calculus is accurate enough according to possibly too big and/or too small values dues to exponentials).

NOTE :

If the parameters $b_i$ are not known, the problem becomes arduous. This is a problem of non-linear regression which is currently tackled with some iterative algorithm, starting from guessed values of the $b_i$. This is a major difficult in practice, especially if they are several $b_i$.

A method which don't requires initial guess, nor iteration comes from : 
https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales , pages 71-74.
The details of calculus process is given for two exponential terms (copy below). Take care that the notations in the referenced paper are not the same as the above notations introduced by JodaDoh.

The extension for more exponential terms is discussed page 74. On a theoretical viewpoint, the method continue to be valid. But, with more exponential terms, the number of parameter becomes large. So, in cases of scattered data, the process might be not robust enough.

[image]